how to sum up using multiple criteria?

i am calculating sum of profits (column O) based on the list of comments as u can see from column V. this is working fine. now i want to add additional criteria where i want it to sum up for me based on week number of the closing date in column D, eg week 25. 25 will be hardcoded for now. i tried for few days but failed. please send help. i have a feeling this is a simple solution.
my current formula:
=SUM(SUMIF($Q$15:$Q$2865, V3:$V$10, $O$15:$O$2865))

thanks in advance!

switch to SUMIFS()

or =SUMIF(AND(...;...)...)

@gns100 i did that too but somehow there is some part not done right leading to error in formula.

Edit your question showing the sumifs formula you tried and what error you are getting. Also read up examples how to use it, as the using greater than and less than construction is a little difficult to figure out for beginners.

Use filter function with both criteria using "()asterisk()" syntax
=SUM(FILTER(profits,(comments=X1)*(dates=25)))

